# There are dense orbits in the set of all allowed sequences

Tags: dynamical-systems, dense-subspaces, topological-dynamics

Lately, I have done an exercise in the book "Introduction to Dynamical Systems" by Brin and Stuck.

> Exercise 1.4.5: Assume that all entries of some power of $A$ are positive. Show that in the product topology on $\sum_A$ and $\sum_A^+$, periodic points are dense and there are dense orbits.

This question was asked in this post
[Periodic points and dense orbits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974134/periodic-points-and-dense-orbits)

The proof for "periodic points are dense" was indicated in the post. Now, I just want to make sure I understand the idea of the proof for the second part.

Assume the alphabet $A_m$ has $m$ elements from 1 to $m$. By our assumption, there is an integer $k$ such that all the entries of $A^k$ is greater than 0. I construct a sequence $y$ as follows:

For any $i,j \in A_m$, if there is a path from $i$ to $j$ after $n$ steps. Let $w$ is a word contains these $n$ symbols. Then consider the sequence of all such $w$'s. For example, for $i=1$ and $j=1$, if there is a path from $1$ to $1$ after 1 step, let $y_1=1, y_2=2$. If there is a path from $1$ to $1$ after 2 steps, let $y_3=1$, $y_5=1$ and so on...

Then we can prove this sequence is dense in $\sum_A^+$.

But I have a question here. Is it possible to construct this sequence?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your construction, but I'll propose a different solution. I will denote the power in your question by $p\in \mathbb{N}$.

Since any shift of a sequence in $\Sigma_A$ or in $\Sigma_{A}^+$ stays in the subshift, you can move it to the $0$ index.

Since finite valid words at $0$, with respect to $A$, induce a basis to the product topology, it is enough to have a sequence containing all valid words.

Enumerate all possible finite words by $\{ w_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$. Now you need to build a sequence with all these words.

For example, put $w_1$ at $0$. Every word $w_n$ starts with a letter $a_n$ and ends at $b_n$. Since $A^p$ has strictly positive entries, there is some valid word $u(b_1,a_2)$ of length $p-2$ such that $b_1 u(b_1,a_2)a_2$ is a valid word. You can then conclude that the concatenation, $w_1u(b_1,a_2)a_2$, is valid. Then $w_1u(b_1,a_2)w_2$ is a valid word as well. You can then recursively construct the locally valid sequence

$$ w_1u(b_1,a_2)w_2u(b_2,a_3)w_3u(b_3,a_4)w_4..., $$

by iterated concatenations. Using the previous arguments, the constructed sequence will have all finite valid words. Therefore, it will have a dense orbit in $\Sigma_A^+$. Similarly, you can construct from this method a sequence $x\in \Sigma_A$ with a dense orbit.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @FactorY You're welcome.